# Box2D flash FPS and performance

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d, frame-rate

I wrote some code on AS3 which uses `Starling` and `Box2D flash`.
I create not more than 15 objects, only 6 movable and 4 joints.
I cant get more than 30 FPS when running on iPhone4. When objects fall into sleep FPS goes up to 60.
Is it even possible to get more than 30 FPS from `Box2D flash`? Maybe some tweaks with iterations and timestep parameters?

Comment: which render mode are you specifying in app descriptor file?

Comment: I am using direct mode, starling won't run in other mode. Before migrating to starling i used flash drawing and different modes and performance wasn't great back than too.

Answer (score 0):

Lowering the number of `velocityIterations` and `positionIterations` in your `world.Step(..)` function will have a direct impact on your framerate, I've gotten away with using as little as 3 and 5 respectively.  Are you setting any of the bodies to act as bullets?

Comment: no bullets, just rectangle with wheels and ground. Ill try lessen iterations.

Comment: I've had a stable 30fps with up to 100 bodies (many small polygons to make smooth terrain) just with debug draw.  That was on Android however, I've heard Flash (AIR to be exact) does run slower on iPhone but not sure about Starling.  Are you using any custom contact listeners or doing anything special when collisions occur?

Comment: I don't have any collision detection turned on now. I also experience micro freezes(few frames get processed a bit slower each few seconds) and it is noticeable but not critical.
Starling is definitely not the bottleneck here(tried disabling all graphics).

Comment: Those freezes might be garbage collector running. You can use Adobe Scout to check that. And what concerns framerate - while Starling can utilize GPU to render all thingies very fast, Box2D runs on CPU and mobile CPUs are slow.